# Use variables outside while loop

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

In my java project i will read a csv file. If the file includes a "nr" with the value 10, I want to print the "name" on the screen.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    scanner = new Scanner(line);
    scanner.useDelimiter(";");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String data = scanner.next();
        if (index == 0)
            nr = Integer.parseInt(data);
            if (nr == 10){
                // ?????
            }
        else if (index == 1)
            name = data;
        else if (index == 2)
            id = data;
        else
            System.out.println("invalid data::" + data);
        index++;
    }
    index = 0;
    forward(nr, name, id);  
}
```

For example my csv is having "nr" 10, two times:

```
10;name1;id1
20;name2;id2
10;name3;id3
```

So i want to print name1 and name3 on the screen, how can i use these variables outside the while loop?

Comment: When you want to print the `name` if `nr` is *10*, then you need to do that in the `else if (index == 1)` block.

Comment: Oke, but  its a huge CSV file, so is it possible to safe these name"s and later print them all in one simple print statement?

Comment: Please don't deface your post

Comment: Can be deleted, fixed it inside the loop...

Comment: Store them in a datastructure, e.g. a String arrays of 2 elements (for the nr and the name) in a list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java programmer, but if I have understood the question correctly, you can define a variable outside of the scope of the While loop and assign it from within. See below.

N.B. In Java, variables can only be used within the scope that they are declared.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (...) {
    list.add("NameToAdd");
}
for(String name: list){
    System.out.print(name);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted as I was correct in my assumption regarding scope?

Comment: I'm not one of the voters, but I guess they did the same mistake as I did. You wrote `"can't you"`, but I read `"you can't"`, that's why I wrote, "Sure you can". Oh and btw: a big thing about answers is: they should answer the question. Even though you gave OP a good direction to solve the problem it is a "please try that" request and this belongs to the comments. Can you please update your question by removing the question and by adding a small example how his code should look like? It would then be a good answer.

Comment: But mind that this may not affect the downvotes, because the voters are not notified about an update of the answer, so they don't see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Tom :)

Comment: Correct about scope. You haven't yet accounted for the idea that there might be more than one name to be printed after the loop exits. Another answer, now deleted, suggested an `ArrayList`. If you incorporated that idea here you'd have an excellent answer.

Comment: Excellent suggestion @ErickG.Hagstrom.

Answer (score 0):

In java variables can't be used outside of the scope they where defined (unlike Javascript for example)

So you have two options to store them in variables defined outside of the loop, or print them the moment you obtain them and not use the name1 and name3 variables at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Input value according to your requirement, here i am using Arralist data:

```
public static void main(String s[]) {

    String name = "", id = "";
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    nameList.add("10;name1;id1");
    nameList.add("20;name2;id2");
    nameList.add("10;name3;id3");
    nameList.add("30;name4;id4");
    nameList.add("10;name5;id5");
    nameList.add("10;name6;id6");

    int index = 0;
    int nr;

    for (String line : nameList) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
        scanner.useDelimiter(";");
        index = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String data = scanner.next();
            //System.out.println(":: " + data + " Index:: " + index);

            if (index == 0) {
                nr = Integer.parseInt(data);
                index++;
                if (nr == 10) {
                    name = scanner.next();
                    id = scanner.next();
                    System.out.println(nr + ";" + name + ";" + id);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Tom mentioned before you can do something like:

```
String str = "";
int nr = 0;
int index = 0;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    scanner = new Scanner(line);
    scanner.useDelimiter(";");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String data = scanner.next();
        if (index == 0)
            nr = Integer.parseInt(data);
        else if (index == 1)
            name = data;
            if (nr == 10)
                str += data + "\n"  
        else if (index == 2)
            id = data;
        else
            System.out.println("invalid data::" + data);
        index++;
    }
    index = 0;
    forward(nr, name, id);  
}
System.out.println(str);
```